# Saving half filled form in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

I am building a long form in Drupal 7. The form contain 3 step to complete. There is certain validation and it is required.

**What I want**: I want to save half filled form in database or other way. All data should fetch out when he logged in again with same or other system. I tried `save_draft` module but it not working perfectly. There is issue of 'not working of next button'.

Hi, I am strongly stuck in this point that after enabling 'save draft' module in Drupal 7,all code are disturb. 
After my some effort I find that there is automatically modify in Id. Below are the code with modified and not modified.

non-modified Id

```
id="edit-field-home-address-type-und-0-premise"
```

modified Id

```
id="edit-field-home-address-type-und-0-premise--2"
```

So please suggest me how to remove all these '--2' extra values from Id from Form in drupal 7.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to send it to the server and save it there probably with JS

Comment: You will have to post some code and the error/problem if you want assistance.

Comment: You want to save progression of user if exit before the end ?

Comment: Yes, Fky I want to save half filled data in form.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [autosave](https://www.drupal.org/project/autosave) a try which saves node form state automatically (without user requiring to press a button)

Not sure if it works with multi step node forms